# Double hit with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I can't get my .htaccess file to be correct and do the thing I want it to do. 
In php, I've written a router to inspect the requested uri.
What I want for the rewrite rules is this:

- Requests to `example.com/images/*` should be rewritten to
  `example.com/view/template/images/*`, but not redirected.
- Requests to `example.com` should be redirected to `example.com/1/`.
- Requests that do not target a file directly should have a trailing slash (with
  redirect).
- Requests that do not target a file directly should be rewritten to `index.php` (invisibly, no redirect).

My current `.htaccess` file complies to all these requirements, but has a serious flaw.
When I go to `example.com`, it is correctly redirected to `example.com/1/` and rewritten to `index.php`, but when I look in the Apache access log, the request is made two times.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2014:16:53:39 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 310 "-" "user-agent..."
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2014:16:53:40 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 310 "-" "user-agent..."
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2014:16:53:39 +0100] "GET /1/ HTTP/1.1" 200 11 "-" "user-agent..."
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2014:16:53:40 +0100] "GET /1/ HTTP/1.1" 200 11 "-" "user-agent..."
```

In `index.php` I have a logger and this one also records two hits.

This is my current `.htaccess`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^favicon.ico$               view/template/images/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$               view/template/images/$1
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$                   view/template/javascript/$1
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$                  view/template/css/$1

RewriteRule ^$                          1/ [R,L]
RewriteRule ^/$                         1/ [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$                      $1/ [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$                        index.php [L]
```

Any ideas what's wrong? Don't shoot me if my `.htaccess` file is completely retarded :-)

Comment: The strange part is, this double hit doesn't always happen. And when I use cURL, it doesn't happen at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^favicon\.ico$              view/template/images/favicon.ico [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(images|js|css)/(.*)$      view/template/$1/$2 [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^$ 1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$  $1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Seems to do the same thing, but only when I go to example.com (without slash). The index.php file is called twice (double entry in the logs).

Comment: If you goto `http://example.com` there will be 2 entries: 1st for `/` and 2nd time with `/1/`

Comment: And is there a way to prevent that from happening?

Comment: That's how you wrote your requirements above. If you comment out `RewriteRule ^$ 1/ [R,L]` then it won't happen.

Comment: But than the default entry point of the website won't be /1/? This should be my main entry point as the /1/ URL refers to page id 1.

Comment: You can make `RewriteRule ^$ 1/ [L]` to avoid URL changing.

Comment: I can try that and add an additional rule in my php router. But isn't it possible to make the redirect to `/1/` prior to rewriting it to `index.php`?

Comment: Rewrite to `index.php` is happening because of `DirectoryIndex`. You can add `DirectoryIndex blablabla.html` to negate that and then `index.php` won't be loaded.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46450/discussion-between-jens-and-anubhava)

Comment: See end of conversation for source of problem: Google Chrome prefetches webpages.

Comment: And refer this link: https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/prerender?hl=ro-RO&csw=1